# rkhunter reports /sbin/ip has changed

Tags: centos, rkhunter

I am using rkhunter 1.4.2 on CentOS 6.5.

A message, in /var/log/rkhunter.log is

```
Warning: The file properties have changed:
[09:40:35]          File: /sbin/ip
[09:40:35]          Current size: 247396    Stored size: 247300
[09:40:35]          Current file modification time: 1415276490 (06-Nov-2014 07:21:30)
[09:40:35]          Stored file modification time : 1401361583 (29-May-2014 07:06:23)
```

I used ip -V  and got

```
  ip -V
  ip utility, iproute2-ss091226
```

which seems to imply it is part of a package from 2009.  I tried to reinstall iproute2 and got the following result.

```
$ sudo yum install iproute2
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, refresh-packagekit, security
Setting up Install Process
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * atomic: www.atomicorp.com
 * base: mirror.lug.udel.edu
 * epel: mirror.nexcess.net
 * extras: mirrors.lga7.us.voxel.net
 * rpmforge: repoforge.mirror.constant.com
 * updates: ftpmirror.your.org
No package iproute2 available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

I got the MD5 for /sbin/ip as follows

```
$ md5sum /sbin/ip
f86d18c6c94096baf9dc6623e9fbe615  /sbin/ip
```

A google search for that MD5 yielded no results so I cannot tell it if corresponds to a legitimate version of /sbin/ip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The package in question is `iproute` not `iproute2` on CentOS.

Without including the architecture, it is hard for others to verify the md5 sum of your executable.  One way to check is to, from a machine you trust, manually pull down the rpm from the centos mirrors, unpack it, and look at the files.

When I do this for the latest versions on mirror.centos.org (2.6.32-33), I get:

```
x86_64 2d08ea6c0e0e8360f7618ba549101fb8  /sbin/ip
  i386 d9bea3a3fda11e9b3822f796601e75d0  /sbin/ip
```

Neither of which matches yours.  If you have concerns, you obviously may want to nuke the machine from orbit. My hunch is that iproute was recently updated.  Looking at the date for the iproute package here:

http://mirror.centos.org/centos/6/updates/x86_64/Packages/

There is a package with last modified time of 06-Nov-2014 14:07.

The fact that your md5sum for this executable doesn't match the above could mean that (0) you have a compromised executable, (1) you aren't updated to the version I checked, (2) you pulled from a local mirror where some administrator rebuilt the package with site-specific compilation flags, (3) the RPM installation went wrong and your executable is wrong because of a failed unpacking or some other error. Or other options I'm sure.

You can also try  `rpm -V -f /sbin/ip` to verify the file against the RPM database.  However, if you have a reason to believe the machine was compromised, doing analysis of it with tools on that same machine is also a bit suspect, since any of them could have been modified to lie to you.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  I foolishly tried to get the sanctioned version of /sbin/ip by using "yum remove iproute" followed by "yum install iproute".  That messed up my system so I restored the image of the disk I made on October 30th using Clonezilla.  rkhunter no longer flagged /sbin/ip either before or after I updated CentOS.  Thanks,